# Italic numbers using Linux Libertine

Tags: xetex, debugging, libertine

I'm trying to typeset a document using `xelatex` with main font Linux Libertine. Here's the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[
  Ligatures      = TeX,
  BoldFont       = {Linux Libertine Bold},
  ItalicFont     = {Linux Libertine Italic},
  BoldItalicFont = {Linux Libertine Bold Italic}
]{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
\textit{1 foo}
\textbf{\emph{1 foo}}
\textbf{1 foo}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, the second and third "1 foo"s appear as they should, but the "1" is missing from the first "1 foo", like this:

[image: Missing '1' in italic]

It seems as though Linux Libertine *does not support italic numerals*.

> What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way to make `xelatex` support the Linux Libertine font in a way that makes italic numerals possible?

If it helps, I'm using TeXWorks on an HP running Windows 8.1.

**Edit:** The only strange thing that shows up in the log file is a warning:

```
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 144.
```

**Edit 2:** When I tweak the document so that the only content is `\textit{0123456789}`, compilation with `xelatex` fails, and the following error is output:

```
** WARNING ** Invalid CMap
** ERROR ** pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.
```

Near the end of the log file, there is a bunch of warnings looking like this:

```
Missing character: There is no   in font Linux Libertine Italic/OT:script=latn;
language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font Linux Libertine Italic/OT:script=latn;
language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;mapping=tex-text;!
```

Comment: I reckon that _Linux_ Libertine is not a standard font of _Windows_ 8.1. I tried to reproduce the problem, and for me it worked with the OTF version of the font. However, it was named Linux Libertine _O_, with an extra capital o at the end. How did you install the font?

Comment: I installed the font from one of the files at the sourceforge page http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/. Should I have installed the font differently?

Comment: No, I guess the source is correct. As said above, I used the OTF version and added a capital o to the font names in your example. Worked for me. Any details in the tex log?

Comment: Perhaps xelatex is finding the wrong font (as xelatex uses a two-step process it can be confused if a font exists twice). Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to the document  and compile with `xelatex --no-pdf file` and `xdvipdfmx -vv file` then inpect the log-file and the output of `xdvipdfmx`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried what you suggested, and there wasn't anything obvious in the log files between what I just mentioned in the second edit.

Comment: And what are the real font files used? (the log-file should mention the pathes.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The fonts are, e.g.: Requested font "Linux Libertine" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf
Requested font "Linux Libertine/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf

Comment: This is nit-picking, but the output you are showing us is _not_ the output of your ``MWE`` (line breaks). So we cannot be sure that the behavior seen in your output isn't caused by something else in the code you actually ran to produce that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `.ttf` fonts, called `Linux Libertine`, and the `.otf` fonts, called `Linux Libertine O`, work fine on my Windows 7 system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[
  BoldFont       = {Linux Libertine Bold},
  ItalicFont     = {Linux Libertine Italic},
  BoldItalicFont = {Linux Libertine Bold Italic}
]{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
\textit{1 foo}
\textbf{\emph{1 foo}}
\textbf{1 foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[
  BoldFont       = {Linux Libertine O Bold},
  ItalicFont     = {Linux Libertine O Italic},
  BoldItalicFont = {Linux Libertine O Bold Italic}
]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\textit{1 foo}
\textbf{\emph{1 foo}}
\textbf{1 foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Something probably went wrong when you installed your fonts, so I suggest you simply reinstall them and try again.

Comment: Not sure why, but on my system, only the `.otf` font `Linux Libertine O` works. No strange warnings or error messages this way either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. I get the following result

[image: libertine]

Comment: It appears that the problem may be with my installation of Linux Libertine rather than with the code. Thanks for checking this.

Comment: @DanielMiller Your code works fine for me, too. I also run TeXworks in a Windows environment. Try re-installing your fonts.

Comment: @Sverre That worked - if you make reinstalling fonts (from OTF not TFF) an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanielMiller Done (although I don't understand why you're saying "not TFF" here, since those are the fonts you used in your ``MWE``, and which work fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}% detects itself the used engine pdftex, xetex, luatex
\begin{document}
\textit{1 foo}
\textbf{\emph{1 foo}}
\textbf{1 foo}
\end{document}
```

The package `libertine` does the correct font setting for you. Install the package from CTAN and the fonts too. Then you have all in the right place.

Comment: I'd like to use xelatex so as to have unicode support. When including the package `libertine`, a bunch of weird fontspec warnings result. Is there any way to have a clean compilation with xelatex and Linux Libertine?

Comment: Sure, as I wrote, the package itself does the setting autimacally for pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex. No need for a specific setting of main, serif and mono font.